# AWS copy quicksight dashboard from one region to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to copy an Amazon QuickSight Dashboard from one region to another?

I only found documentation for coping in the same region
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/copying-a-dashboard.html

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your dashboard from one region to the other using the API, but be aware that you have to go all the way - starting with the datasource, the dataset, the templates, etc.